# Scalar potential vector

Tags: homework-and-exercises, potential, integration, vector-fields

I am trying to find the scalar potential, $\phi(\vec r)$, of a conservative vector field $\vec a(\vec r)$. I am integrating along a straight line from $\vec r_0$ to $\vec r$ which is parametrised by $\vec r^\prime = \lambda\vec r$ with $0\le\lambda\le1$. Thus $d\vec r^\prime=d\lambda\vec r$ and hence:$$\phi(\vec r)=\int_0^\vec r \vec a(\vec r^\prime)\cdot d\vec r^\prime=\int_{\lambda=0}^{\lambda=1} \vec a(\lambda\vec r)\cdot \vec r d\lambda$$

The conservative vector field I am using is $\vec a=\vec rf(r)$ where $f(r)$ is an arbitrary function of $r=|\vec r|$.

Therefore, $$\phi(\vec r)=\int_{\lambda=0}^{\lambda=1} \vec a(\lambda\vec r)\cdot \vec r d\lambda=\int_{0}^{1} \lambda\vec rf(\lambda r)\cdot \vec r d\lambda\: [\star]$$
$$=\int_{0}^{1} \lambda^2(\vec r\cdot \vec r)f(r) d\lambda\:[\star\star]=(\vec r\cdot \vec r)f(r)\int_{0}^{1} \lambda^2 d\lambda $$
$$=\frac{1}{3}(\vec r\cdot \vec r)f(r)=\frac{1}{3}r^2f(r)$$

Next, in order to verify that I have obtained the correct scalar potential I use the fact that:
$$\vec a=\nabla \phi (\vec r) $$
$$\vec a=\nabla(\frac{1}{3}r^2f(r))=\frac{1}{3}((\nabla r^2)f(r)+(\nabla f(r))r^2)$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}(\vec r f(r) + f^\prime (r)(\nabla r)r^2)=\frac{1}{3}(\vec r f(r) + f^\prime (r)(r^{-1}\vec r)r^2)$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}(\vec r f(r) + f^\prime (r)r^{-1}\vec r)$$

I am supposed to get back my vector $\vec a=\vec rf(r)$ but this is not the case. I believe that there is potentially something wrong at $[\star]$ or $[\star\star]$.

I would like to know where I have gone wrong in order to get back my original vector.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that you lost a factor $\lambda$: $f(\lambda r) \rightarrow f(r)$

Comment: @Vadim I took the $\lambda$ out and put it into the $\lambda^2$ factor to be integrated. Have I treated the $\lambda$ wrong? How should I treat it?

Comment: @Vadim Can you give me further guidance?

Comment: Generally speaking this is incorrect, since $f(r)$ is an arbitrary function, $f(\lambda r)\neq \lambda f(r)$

Comment: @Vadim So do you know what I should do instead? I do not know how to correctly perform $$\int f(\lambda r)\:d\lambda$$.

Comment: I think that you will have to leave it in general form, or as an integral over $r'$ (without vector)

Comment: @Vadim So if I had the limits of integration: $$\int_{0}^{1} f(\lambda r)\:d\lambda$$ What will that become?

Comment: Hint : Take as straight line the $x-$axis with unit vector $\mathbf{i}$. On this line
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{a}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{=}f(r)\mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{\cdot}\mathrm{d}\mathbf{r}\boldsymbol{=}f(x)(x\mathbf{i})\boldsymbol{\cdot}(\mathrm{d}x\mathbf{i})\boldsymbol{=}f(x)x\mathrm{d}x
\tag{01}
\end{equation} 
so that the parameter is the $x-$coordinate on the non-negative semi-axis.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know where I have gone wrong in order to get back my original vector.

You went wrong at the step $[\star]$, when you substituted $f(\lambda r)\rightarrow \lambda f(r)$, because in principle we don't know if $f$ is linear or not. Therefore the only thing you can do is leave the potential as
$$\phi(\vec{r})=r^2\int_0^1\lambda f(\lambda r)d\lambda\ .$$

From here you can recover the field taking the gradient. Don't let the fact that the expression depends on $\lambda$ intimidate you.

Since the potential actually depends only on $r=|\vec{r}|$, the gradient is $\nabla\phi=\hat{r}\displaystyle\frac{d\phi}{dr}$. Hence remembering the product rule for derivatives and the chain rule

\begin{align}
\vec{a}&=\hat{r}\left[2r\int_0^1\lambda f(\lambda r)d\lambda+r^2\frac{d}{dr}\int_0^1\lambda f(\lambda r)d\lambda\right]\\
&=\hat{r}\left[r\int_0^12\lambda f(\lambda r)d\lambda+r^2\int_0^1\lambda^2 f'(\lambda r)d\lambda\right]
\end{align}

If we now notice that $$\frac{d}{d\lambda}\left[\lambda^2 f(\lambda r)\right]=2\lambda f(\lambda r)+\lambda^2rf'(\lambda r)$$

it follows immediately that
$$\vec{a}=\vec{r}\int_{\lambda=0}^{\lambda=1}d[\lambda^2f(\lambda r)]=\vec{r}f(r)\ .$$

Answer (score -2):

Since $\vec a$ a conservative vector field, $\nabla \times \vec a=0 \iff$ $\vec a=\nabla \phi(\vec r)$ - and the intergal of $\nabla \phi(\vec r)$ is path independent: $\int_\gamma\nabla\phi(\vec r)\cdot d\vec r =\phi(\vec r_b)-\phi(\vec r_{a})$. The integral only depends upon the beginning and ending points.

Hence, $$\int^{r_b}_{r_a}\vec r f(r)\cdot d\vec r=\int^{r_b}_{r_a}\nabla\phi(\vec r)\cdot d\vec r =\phi(r_b)-\phi(r_{a})$$
or
$$\int^{r_b}_{r_a} r f(r) dr=\int^{r_b}_{r_a}{\partial}_r\phi(r)dr=\phi(r_b)-\phi(r_{a})$$

where $f(r)$ is unknown.

Comment: When I perform the check on $rf(r)$ via $\vec a=\nabla \phi(\vec r)$ I get $f(r)\vec r r^{-1} + f^\prime (r)\vec r$, which is not the same as the original $\vec a$. Hence $\phi(\vec r) \ne rf(r)$. Can you explain how you got that potential?

Comment: My main problem is knowing how to correctly treat the $f(\lambda r)$ when integrating

Comment: @Σbaryon: I showed you how I got the potential.  It's a piece of cake - look up the curl of conservative vector field. It gives you the potential directly.

Comment: @Σbaryon: you don't have a path parameterization - you're just multiplying  $\vec r$ by $\lambda$. You need $\vec r=\vec r(\lambda)$ - which you don't have. Further, you don't have $f(r)$. And you don't even know if the path is a straight line.

Comment: I will give you some background information:https://imgur.com/qeyVeES. It states here that the integration is taking place over a straight line.

Comment: I am integrating from the start point, $\lambda = 0$, to the end point of the vector, $\lambda = 1$, so there is no path dependence. I just do not know how to correctly parametrise the arbitrary function, $f(r)$, and how to integrate it, which is what I need in order to find the scalar potential using the method outlined in the notes that I linked.

Comment: @Σbaryon: and yet you missed the part about the intergal being path indpendent. That doesn't mean you integerate along a straight line - that would be path dependent - it means the intergral only depends upon the starting point and the ending point.

Comment: @CinaedSimoson I don't think your answer is correct - taking the gradient shows it: $\nabla (rf(r))= \mathbf{r}/r\partial_r(rf(r))= \mathbf{r}/r[f(r)+f'(r)]$

Comment: @Vadim: $\nabla(rf(r))$  is the gradient!  Expand if you like but it's still the gradient. The solution to this problem is simple vector calculus. Google for curl of a gradient and then path intergal of gradient.

Comment: @CinaedSimson My understanding is that given is vector field: $\vec{a}=\vec{r}f(r)$. It is certainly a gradient, but not the gradient of $rf(r)$.